# Arrays.sort implementation, what does it do specifically

Tags: java, sorting

What sorting algorithm does Arrays.sort use in Java?  Does it change dynamically depending on operating system, or input size or something?

Comment: You can just take a look at the source code, that you already should be having on your machine.

Comment: Note that this is covered in [`Arrays#sort` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: @RohitJain I don't have the source code on my machine I don't think... I have the binaries.

Comment: Not really related, but you might find Java 8's [`Arrays.parallelSort`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b84/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort%28int[]%29) interesting.

Comment: @arshajii That is awesome, didn't know it existed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The doc doesn't provide the details I needed. Didn't realize the source was available so easily online... luckily Peter took care of me :)

Comment: @AA the sources are available on your jdk distribution as well under the `src.zip` file inside bin folder of your JAVA_HOME folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the source what it does on OpenJDK.  For primitive types, it uses insertion sort for short arrays and a modified quicksort for longer ones; and tim sort for object arrays.

[Java 6 Arrays.sort()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort1%28long%5B%5D,int,int%29)

I don't see how the OS would effect sorting.

Comment: Timsort is a hybrid sort somewhere between mergesort and insertion sort- don't think that quicksort went into it. It is only used in java7 though.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Peter, don't mind my edit: quicksort is unstable, therefore only applicable to primitives. And  timsort is used for object arrays of all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive,
>   iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons
>   when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the
>   performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is
>   randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the
>   implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage
>   requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays
>   to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending
>   order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and
>   descending order in different parts of the the same input array. It is
>   well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate
>   the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python
>   ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting
>   and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth
>   Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January
>   1993.

Take a look at the source code: [`Arrays.sort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Comment: This applies to `sort(Object[])` only.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` method is overloaded.

For Java 7 look at the implementation notes for different types starting from  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5B%5D%29) and further down.